# Kendo Grid & Rich text Editor of Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, telerik

I'm using custom grids (Kendo UI Core free version) into an sharepoint 365 APP. I would like to use the Rich text Editor of sharepoint 2013 when I edit some fields. is this possible?

Comment: Hi Robert , I do not agree with your opinion for two reasons :
1 - Telerik Kendo UI core is free and open source 
2 - this is not a problem but a question how to show on demand the rich text editor of sharepoint 2013 c

Comment: You have clarified that since the question was closed. Now it makes more sense to reopen it. But, you are probably still more likely to get answers from Telerik's community